# Rebase based on remote commit sometimes give 'fatal: invalid upstream' error

Tags: git, gerrit

The scenario is like this: I create a local branch feature1

```
[local] main - feature1
```

I pushed the changes on `feature1` to `origin main`.

```
[origin] main - change1
```

I edited something on change1 through the UI (maybe changed the title, or rebased on a different change)

```
[origin] main - change1-1
```

now I want my local branch `feature1` to be updated based on `change1-1`.
In a scenario like this, I tried either `rebase` or `checkout`.

```
git switch feature1
git fetch origin
git rebase <SHA-of-change1-1>
or 
git checkout <SHA-of-change1-1>
```

Sometimes this works but other times it does not and I honestly don't know what's the difference in each case.

When rebase doesn't work, I see

```
fatal: invalid upstream <SHA-of-change1-1>
```

When checkout doesn't work, I see

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: <SHA-of-change1-1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

You may need to set up your Git to fetch `refs/changes/*`:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*"
```

Later, you might consider using `refs/changes/` directly, or continuing to use raw commit hash IDs.

## Long (but if you use Gerrit, do read it)

There may be multiple issues to untangle here.  Let's start with the first one, which is unimportant on its own *today* but will someday matter: Git no longer refers to commit IDs as *SHA* or *SHA-1* hash IDs as Git now supports, internally, multiple different hashing algorithms.  So for *Git* these are *object IDs* or *OIDs*.  However, for good and important reasons, almost nobody is using anything other than SHA-1 hashes anyway, so the OIDs are almost always SHA-1 hash IDs anyway.   But a *Git commit hash* is no longer called an "SHA".

Second—and this may be much more important—*Gerrit* assigns *its own* change-ID to *a series of commits* used to implement some actual change.  [These Gerrit change-IDs start with the letter `I`.](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html)  A Gerrit change ID strongly resembles an SHA-1 because Gerrit actually runs some Git operations to generate a Git hash ID, and as long as the generated Git hash ID is internally an SHA-1 hash ID (as it usually is) you get an SHA-1.  Then Gerrit pastes the letter `I` on the front, which never appears in a real SHA-1 hash ID as those are expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

The reason that Gerrit generates this change-ID is so that *Gerrit* can keep track of the commit(s) used to accomplish some task.  The set of commits that *achieve the desired result* will evolve over time, but they'll keep the same *change-ID* so that they can be clustered together for reviewing and other administrative steps needed while shepherding the bug fix or enhancement or whatever this may be through the process of getting it into the software.  *Git* knows nothing about this Gerrit entity: Git knows only about commits.

So here's what to keep in mind at this point:

- *Git* uses an *object ID* to locate any one given commit.  This object ID specifies *exactly one commit*, and no two *different* commits *ever* re-use a Git hash ID.  **A Git hash ID never starts with `I`.**
- *Gerrit* uses a *change ID* to locate one "Gerrit change".  This ID is foreign to Git; Git will be confused if you ever hand this ID *to* Git.  Never give this ID directly to Git.  However, *Gerrit* will use this ID to locate "the set of changes" (some cluster of one or more commits) for some Gerrit-level task: always use the same *Gerrit* ID for that task, so that Gerrit can keep track of it.  Don't give Gerrit a *Git* hash ID.  **A Gerrit change-ID always starts with `I`.**

Hence the `I` IDs go to Gerrit, while the non-`I` IDs **might** work with Git.  The word *might* is here because your problem might not actually be any of the above.

#### Git-level fetch operations

You mentioned that

> I edited something on change1 through the UI (maybe changed the title, or rebased on a different change)

*Git* does not have this kind of UI.  Some Git hosting sites do add on their own UI, but Git is not aware of them.  At the Git command-line level—where you run the `git rebase`, `git cherry-pick`, `git log`, `git checkout`, and other such Git commands<sup>1</sup>—Git won't know about anything you've done here.

> now I want my local branch feature1 to be updated based on change1-1. In a scenario like this, I tried either rebase or checkout.
>
> ```
> git switch feature1
> git fetch origin
> git rebase <SHA-of-change1-1>
> or 
> git checkout <SHA-of-change1-1>
> ```
>
> Sometimes this works but other times it does not and I honestly don't know what's the difference in both cases.

The `git fetch origin` step here is necessary and causes, or at least can cause, your *Git* software to pick up any new commits *from* the Git server that the Gerrit system is using on whatever hosting system you are using here.

The likely problem, however, is that a *Gerrit* change—which may consists of one or more *Git* **commits**—is not itself a Git entity.  Any new commits you made with some UI will be *in* the Gerrit Git server at this point, but they're probably under a *name* that Git does not know about.  This is where we get into some of the esoteric and exotic bits of Git.

Git actually uses hash IDs (which we are not supposed to call "SHA" any more even though they probably still are SHA-1 IDs) to uniquely identify commits.  A `git fetch` operation will *often*, but not *always*, get any new commits from some other Git repository.  The tricky part is that this transfer operation from the other Git depends on *names* stored in that other Git repository.

The normal *names* that we (humans) use, as stored in any ordinary everyday Git repository, start with `refs/heads/`, `refs/tags/`, and `refs/remotes/`.  These prefix strings assign the names to a [*namespace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) (sometimes called a name-space, hyphenated, or a name space, two words): those in `refs/heads/` are *branch names*, those in `refs/tags/` are *tag names*, and those in `refs/remotes/` are *remote-tracking names*.

When you run `git fetch origin` (or just `git fetch`), this has your Git software call up their Git software, connect to their Git repository, and list out their names, including their branch and tag names.  Your Git software then pores over their branch and tag names, looking for commits that are new to you.  On finding such commits, your Git software brings those commits over to *your* Git repository.

If you obtain these commits, you can then refer to them by their Git commit hash IDs (their Git-level OIDs).  If you *have the commits* and use the *Git* OID, this *always works*.  But:

- you need to *have the commits*, and
- you need to use the *Git OID*, not the Gerrit ID.

I'm guessing that your particular problem is most likely the first of these two points, and that's because when someone updates a Gerrit change-request with some new commits, *Gerrit* tells Git to *store the latest Git ID* under a name that does not fit the above patterns.

Before we move on to describe the Gerrit naming system, let's finish off the last bits about `git fetch`.  Because of the way Gerrit does things, this doesn't matter *yet*, but it will in the next section.

Having seen their branch names and hash IDs, your own Git software *renames* their *branch* names to become your *remote-tracking names*.  So their Git branch name `main` becomes your remote-tracking name `origin/main`; their Git branch name `develop` becomes your remote-tracking name `origin/develop`; their Git branch name `feature/tall` becomes your remote-tracking name `origin/feature/tall`; and so on.  The renaming takes their branch name and sticks `origin/` in front, with the `origin` part coming from the fact that we ran `git fetch origin` (or if we ran `git fetch`, it meant `git fetch origin`).  Git moves their *branch* name-space names into our *remote-tracking* name-space, and sticks the `origin/` in front so that if we have more than one *remote*, this all works.<sup>2</sup>

A Git branch name *always means* the *last* commit that we should refer to as being "in" or "on" that branch.  (That's how Git defines a branch name: whatever hash ID is stored in it, that is the hash ID of the last commit "on" that branch.)  So after `git fetch`, our Git updates our *remote-tracking names* to match their *branch* names, and hence our remote-tracking names work just as well for us as their *branch* names work for them.  Should we want to see the latest commit on *their* `develop` branch, we can just ask Git to show us the latest commit on our `origin/develop` remote-tracking name.

**Note that you *do* have to run `git fetch` often.**  Git is not constantly on-line: it only picks up new commits *when you run `git fetch`*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that Gerrit adds its own command-line commands to this set.  For instance, `git review` is actually a *Gerrit* command, not a Git command.  So you can't use the `git` part of the command to assume that something is a lower-level *Git* command.

<sup>2</sup>Most people mostly only ever have one remote in their setup.  You can use `git remote add` to add a second remote, after which you'll have a second set of remote-tracking names.  If you run `git remote add r2 url` and then `git fetch r2`, you'll have your Git fill in a bunch of `refs/remotes/r2/*` names, which `git branch -r` will show as `r2/main`, `r2/develop`, `r2/feature/tall`, and so on.  Here `r2` is another *remote* and the `r2/*` names are more *remote-tracking names*.

The usual `origin` and `origin/*` are the usual *first* remote and remote-tracking names.  The `git clone` command sets up `origin` *as* the first remote, and then runs an initial `git fetch origin` for you.  Most people make most of their Git repositories using `git clone`, so most people have one remote, named `origin`, in most of their Git repositories.

---

#### The special Gerrit namespaces

To shepherd Git commits around inside Gerrit, [Gerrit makes use of several namespaces that the Gerrit folks made up](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#references).  One namespace starts with `refs/for/` and goes on to include a branch name, like `master` or `main`, or `develop`, or `feature1`, or whatever.

To use this, you make your set of changes and then run:

```
git push origin feature1:refs/for/feature1
```

This particular name-space is quite specially magic and fake: the incoming commits here are *read by Gerrit* and never put into `refs/for/` at all.  (Your Git software will see these as having been accepted, and will *think* that their Git created or updated `refs/for/feature1`, but it didn't.)

The second namespace here that Gerrit creates and uses starts with `refs/changes/`.  Once a change has a Gerrit change-ID assigned, each series of Git commits is given an appropriate magic `refs/changes/` name.  The Gerrit documentation (linked above) describes this space this way:

> Under this namespace each uploaded patch set for every change gets a static reference in their git. The format is convenient but still intended to scale to hundreds of thousands of patch sets. To access a given patch set you will need the change number and patch set number.
>
> `refs/changes/last two digits of change number/change number/patch set number`
>
> You can also find these static references linked on the page of each change.

If you make your Git software fetch these names, that will force your Git software to download all the *commits*.  Note that you will get every reviewable commit you are allowed to get!  This namespace apparently has Gerrit-side access controls enforced, so you may not have permission to view some or all names; if so, that may be an insurmountable problem and you may have to avoid using the UI (or get your Gerrit administrator to give you read permission).  Not having used Gerrit, I base all of this on what I have read in the pages linked above.

In any case, assuming that the `refs/changes/*` trick works, you will now have the commit(s) you need.  You can refer to them by Git's hash ID (remember not to call this an "SHA" any more) and it will work, regardless of whether you use:

> ```
> git rebase <SHA-of-change1-1>
> ```

or

> ```
> git checkout <SHA-of-change1-1>
> ```

The **base requirement** here is that your Git have the object, so that the hash ID works, and that you use the correct raw Git hash ID, not the Gerrit change-ID.  We fulfill this base requirement by running:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*"
```

once in our clone, so that `git fetch origin` reads and copies all of their `refs/changes/*` names to our own repository, forcing our Git to pick up the appropriate Git objects.<sup>3</sup>

**But** now that you have `refs/changes/*` you might want to use the Gerrit change-ID.  As I quoted above, the `refs/changes/zz/Ixxxxxxx...xxzz/1` (or maybe `refs/changes/zz/xxxx...zz/1` or `/01` or whatever it might be) *name* will hold the correct Git hash ID.  By looking at the special name-space names, you can refer back to earlier sets of commits posted for review.

(Whether the Git raw hash ID, or the Gerrit-generated Gerrit change-ID, is more convenient for you is another question entirely.  There's probably some add-on software that lets you deal with this even-more-conveniently, and if not, you could write your own.)

---

<sup>3</sup>If you know what you're doing, you can add this to your global Git configuration, or to an included config for all Gerrit clones, or whatever.  It's generally harmless to ask for refs that do not exist this way, but it's always a good idea to know what you're doing before you set anything like this up with `--global`.

---

#### Notes on Git `rebase`, `checkout`, and `switch`

You mentioned:

> When rebase doesn't work, I see
>
> ```
> fatal: invalid upstream <SHA-of-change1-1>
> ```
>
> When checkout doesn't work, I see
>
> ```
> fatal: reference is not a tree: <SHA-of-change1-1>
> ```

The reason for this gets into some "gritty details", as the Gerrit documentation puts it, about how rebase and checkout work.

Git stores almost everything as a *commit*.  A commit has a unique hash ID—the thing we're not supposed to call "SHA" any more—that locates that commit within Git's big all-objects database.  But what's *in* a commit anyway?  The answer is two-fold:

- Every commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*.  The files inside the commit are stored in a special, read-only, compressed (sometimes highly compressed) and *de-duplicated* form, so given that most commits mostly re-use earlier commits' files, and those that don't mostly make a small *change* to a file, these archived versions of each file can take remarkably little space.  The duplicates are all elided entirely and the similar files eventually (but not immediately—this part is tricky) use [delta compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) so that *they* take hardly any space, to the point where the stored archive files *in* a repository may take *less space* than the usable, editable files you get on a check-out.
- At the same time, each commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  We won't go into any detail here as we won't get deep enough into rebasing to need it.

To let you use the files *in* a commit, Git must *extract* those files.  The stored files are in a useless format: nothing but Git can read them, and literally nothing, not even Git itself, can overwrite them.  Usable files need to be readable *and writable*.  So a `git switch` or `git checkout` takes a commit hash ID and uses this to locate the snapshot-of-all-files that acts as the permanent archive.  Git calls this a *tree*, and it's why you see:

> ```
> fatal: reference is not a tree ...
> ```

if you give Git an ID that it cannot use as a commit object (which then locates a tree object), and that Git cannot use directly as a tree object either.

The `git switch` command *requires* a *branch name*, as in:

```
git switch feature1
```

unless you use the `--detach` operation, but the `git checkout` operation will automatically *assume* `--detach` if you give it a commit or tree hash ID.  Both commands, given `--detach` (or assuming it if appropriate), will enter Git's *detached HEAD* mode and check out the tree associated with some commit, given the commit's ID.  You can then look at all the files, or build them, or do whatever you like.

Note that the files *extracted from* the commit are *not in Git*.  The files that *are* in Git are the compressed, de-duplicated, Git-ified archives.  These can be—and in fact were—used to *produce* the usable files that you just got, but any changes you make *to* those produced files are also not in Git.  You must `git add` and `git commit` them to make Git store a new commit.

The `git rebase` command is more complicated than the `git checkout` or `git switch` command.  When we use `git rebase`, we are telling Git that we have some commits—one or more commits in a series—where we like *some* things *about* those commits, and *dislike* some other things about them.  Now, the fact is that *all* Git commits are *completely read-only*.  Nothing about any Git commit can ever be changed, not even by Git itself.  But there is something about the existing commits that we don't like: something we *want* to change.

The way Git allows us to do this is that Git lets us build a *new series of commits* from the original commits.  When we use it in its fanciest form, as `git rebase -i`, it:

- checks out the last commit we *don't* want to change;
- uses `git cherry-pick` to apply, but not actually commit, the first of the commits we'd *like* to change; then
- stops in the middle of this interactive rebase.

This gives us a chance to take the files in our working tree—which are now ordinary everyday files and *can* be changed—and *change* them if we like.  Then we run `git add` and `git commit`, or perhaps `git rebase --continue` will will run `git commit` for us, to make a *new and different* commit with whatever we *don't* like fixed up.  That could be as simple as changing the log message in the metadata, or as complicated as we like, making many changes to many source files.  But no matter what, we've taken our original commit—which we liked *some* things about, but not *everything*—and used it to make a *new and different commit*, which gets a new and different hash ID.  Once the corrected commit is in place, rebase can move on to later commits, copying *those* to new-and-improved commits as well.  When rebase has made the last necessary copy, it stores the hash ID of the *last* of the new-and-improved commits into the branch name.  Since the branch name by definition says which commit is the *last* one, that completes the operation.

With interactive rebase, we get lots of control here.  With other kinds of rebase operations, we give up some or all of this control, letting us do less, but get it done more easily.  There's a general principle at work here that, when rephrased into a Spider-Man movie or comic book, becomes [*With great power comes great responsibility*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_great_power_comes_great_responsibility).  If we give up a lot of the power, we can be a lot less careful and responsible and still get the right result.  That's why we have less- and more-powerful tools in Git, so that we can use the right tool for the job.<sup>4</sup>

In any case, the main thing about `git rebase` that is very different from `git checkout` is that rebase *copies one or more commits to new and improved commits*.  It does not merely *check out* a single commit.  So it literally cannot use a raw *tree* ID.  It needs a *commit* hash ID.  That's why the error message here says:

> ```
> fatal: invalid upstream ...
> ```

The hash ID we supply *must* be that of a commit, and rebase calls that particular commit the *upstream* commit.  Rebase actually needs two hash IDs: an *upstream* and an *onto*.  However, a lot of the time, the two IDs can be specified *using* a *single* ID or name.  When that's the case, we just supply the one ID or name and Git figures out the other on its own.  When we do need both IDs we run `git rebase --onto onto upstream`, with the *`onto`* argument supplying the "onto" hash ID and the *`upstream`* argument supplying only the upstream.  When we don't use `--onto`, the *`upstream`* argument is actually the *`onto`* and Git figures out the *real* *`upstream`* on its own—but Git still calls this the *`upstream`* in its messages and in [the `git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

---

<sup>4</sup>Note that the same principle holds in many other places.  A properly equipped woodworking shop does not have just one kind of saw, one kind of rasp or file, one chisel, one hammer, and so on.  But you wouldn't use a hand saw to rip plywood sheathing for a house, and you wouldn't use a drill press to make holes for upholstery tacks.  You need the right tool for the job.

Comment: I’d like to thank you @torek at the cost of being deleted (mods in Stackoverflow seem to delete appreciative comments) for providing a fun read that cleared up a great part of my unorganized knowledge! I have a few things to sort out on my own after reading this but this is still a great start.